# Why have tag and id as a selector without a space or chevron?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am a software developer who focusses more on the domain model and backend.  I am looking at some front end code (css like this):

```
ul#flex-container {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    display: flex;
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
  <div id="container">
    <ul id="flex-container">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    </div>
```

I understand the concept of descendant selectors and parent selectors.  However, why have:

```
ul#flex-container
```

The reason I ask is because:

```
flex-container
```

works on its own.  I understand there is a reason for this, but I cannot find an answer.

Comment: @FluffyKitten, thanks for that - I have bookmarked that question as it is helpful.  However, it does not explain why the tag and id is used as a selector rather than just the id.

Comment: The selector `flex-container` will not work on its own, unless you have a custom element with the name `flex-container` (e.g., `<flex-container></flex-container>`)

Comment: It is for specificity, but its impossible to say why it is being used in your code as there are various reason to make it more specific, e.g. to override an existing CSS rule that has the selector `ul#flex-container` (`#flex-container` is less specific and won't override the more specific selector), or if you only want to select lists with that id (`#flex-container` will select *any* element with that id, `ul#flex-container` will select the element *if* it is a `ul`). There are links to documentation in the answer to the question above, take a browse through those, it might help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten, but element IDs have to be unique?

Comment: @FluffyKitten, thanks.  There can be multiple html web pages accessing the css.  Just realised this.

Comment: If you would like to post an answer then please do and I will accept.

Comment: They must be unique in *that* page. CSS files are usually included site-wide. Or it could be a library used in many sites. As I said, it is impossible to tell in you example, but there are *many* possible reasons in web development.

Comment: There is no need to post an answer if you think answer above covers it? :)

Comment: @ FluffyKitten, yes I agree - it was just so I could give some credit.

Comment: I've added an answer after all, as the comments above answer your question "why", whereas that the linked answer concentrates on the what it is and how it works. I added some more info and included some links too that might help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible reasons.

- It increases [specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)
- While an ID must be unique within a page, it doesn't have to be unique within a website. Another webpage that uses the same stylesheet might use the ID on a different type of element to which those styles should not be applied.
- The type is provided as a hint for people reading the code so they know what type of element it is applied to.

Comment: Does it increase specificity over using the ID alone i.e. without the tag?

Comment: @w0051977 — Yes. When I said "It increases specificity" it was in the context of the question you asked.

Comment: Thanks.  If you put a space in between then it is known as a descendant selector.  If you put a chevron, then it is known  as a parent/child relationship.  What is the relationship described as if there is no space?

Comment: A space is a descendant combinator. A greater-than sign is a child combinator. Nothing is nothing.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by: "nothing is nothing".

Comment: There isn’t a name for the absence of any kind of combinator.

Comment: So why have it (there must be a reason).  +1 for the reference to specificity.

Comment: I assume that it is saying the #flex-container must be the id of a ul, but I am not sure.

Comment: @w0051977 — I suggested three possible reasons in the answer. The fact that there is no specific name for it doesn’t nullify any of them. And yes, multiple selectors without a combinator all refer to features of the same element.

Comment: "multiple selectors without a combinator all refer to features of the same element".  I think that was what I was looking for.  When you say: "without a combinator" does that mean without a space?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#combinators

Comment: @w0051977 “*So why have it (there must be a reason)*” - I also gave you examples of possible reasons in my comments and answer :) with the first comment being specificity which is the most likely reason (as I expanded on in my answer). But as I also said, without knowing how it is used in your project it’s not possible to tell for sure.

Comment: @w0051977 “*I assume that it is saying the #flex-container must be the id of a ul, but I am not sure*”, yes that is exactly what it’s saying, as I mentioned in my comments. It doesn’t need a name because it is just a more specific *selector* to target an element by “what it is” essentially.

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed in the comments above, it is for specificity. Its impossible to say why it is being used in your code, but there are various reasons to make a CSS selector more specific, e.g.

- **to override an existing CSS rule** (Note that this is probably the more common reason for a selector with more specificity when using ids). For example, consider a CSS rule has the selector `ul#flex-container`: `#flex-container` is less specific and won't override the more specific selector. Also, even of the existing CSS only uses `#flex-container`, if it is included *after* your CSS rule it will override it - making it more specific will stop the later less-specific rule overriding it.
- **if you only want to select elements of a particular type that have that id**. `#flex-container` will select any element with that id, `ul#flex-container` will select the element if it is a `ul`.

Note that although IDs must be unique as you say, they only need to be unique within that page. CSS files are usually generally included site-wide (i.e. not just on a single page), or it could even be part of a library used in many sites.

Here are some additional links that offer more detail about specificity in general:

- [MDN web docs: Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)
- [CSS Tricks: Specifics on Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: Thanks for the references on specificity.  I have seen them before, but relevant to the question +1.